ZYNQ FPGA Develope tool chain on mac
I have an Macbook m3, and a third party ZYNQ 7020 board. I understand that Xilinx doesn't support macos platform at this stage. but I wondering if anyone can show me an toolchain to develop PL and PS on Macos?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

the name is  macOS, not macos ... please correct your post

I'm not a macOS user, but do Running Xilinx Vivado on an M1 Mac or Running Vivado on ARM64 Mac using Rosetta 2 help?
